# Integral form of a "generalized" Bessel potential

Tags: harmonic-analysis

The Bessel potential is defined by $(I-\Delta)^{-\alpha/2}$ and it has an integral kernel $K$ such that $(I-\Delta)^{-\alpha/2}f = K*f$. Is there a way to generalize this to something like
$$ (g-\Delta)^{-\alpha/2}f = \tilde{K}* f$$
where $g$ is some given function? And if so, what are the conditions on $g$?

Comment: Since convolution operators are translation-invariant, heuristics would suggest that the function $g$ has to be translation-invariant for this to work out. But a translation-invariant function is just a constant function, so that would be a pretty restrictive condition.